# setting SUID on JTree?

Tags: java, swing, jtree

Here is my question: I have been working on a complex product (100k+ lines of code)  which essentially attaches up to 8 different classes to a `JTree` structure and serialises the entire entity to disk. I am setting the SUID in each of my own classes to facilitate version management and this all works fine. I have been doing all testing in `JDK1.7`  via a textPad development tool. So far so good.

I launched my app using the `JRE(1.7)` (for the first time last week) and it falls over with a deserialization version error. The error comes from the deserialzation of the JTree and not my classes.

This raises two issues:

1. Why is a core data structure such as a `JTree` not universally deserialisable within the same JAVA release? Surely there is no version change between JRE Swing and JDK Swing within the 1.7 release?
2. Can I set the SUID in a `JTree` (or other) Swing component?

Can anyone see a solution please?

Answer (score 1):

From the [J2SE documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/JPanel.html): "Warning: Serialized objects of this class will not be compatible with future Swing releases. The current serialization support is appropriate for short term storage or RMI between applications running the same version of Swing. As of 1.4, support for long term storage of all JavaBeansTM has been added to the java.beans package. Please see XMLEncoder."

Comment: Thanks Pedro but alas I think there is more to it since I am working within the current release and not a "new" release. One could argue that my current issue is indeed a "short term storage" ie create the data structure in JDK1.7 and try to read it 1 minute later in JRE1.7. There is something very wrong here because it defeats the whole purpose of serialisation if it cant remain valid for 1 minute in the same supposed version of Swing. cheers

Comment: Are you using 1.7.a here and 1.7.b there? Maybe the vendor will agree with you that a bug has been introduced. It depends on the vendor's definition of "same version".

Comment: Hi again Pedro. The plot thickens. Firstly, The java version is 1.7b5. Since I posted my query, I have been experimenting. Issuing: ObjectStreamClass.lookup("SwingComponent".class).getSerialVersionUID(). was very interesting! The SUID is different for many Swing components between JRE1.7 and JDK1.7. This is silly of course. It means that code developed and tested in the JDK will not run under the JRE which is supposedly the same release of Swing. ugh!. Will post a comment re your suggestion of XMLEncoder shortly (running out of chars in this post)

Comment: XMLEncoder is not a good option for our application either because the file produced is too large, unsecured and slow. Since we dont care about being locked into a version, I would appreciate your thoughts on sucking the javax package out of the JDK, tossing it into a jar and locking into that swing version forever. Any other ideas to maintain the serialization paradigm would be appreciated - PS thanks for your time in chatting :) – Karl

Comment: But is all this truly a problem? Are you expecting instances of the application to be run by a variety of J2SE implementations, such that data produced yesterday would be illegible tomorrow? Just fix the J2SE implementation on your production environment.

Comment: You are of course quite correct and indeed that would suffice. I have just been exploring storing the entire tree structure and data model as a vector (Free of SUIDs of course) and storing that instead. Now the data could be loaded into any version of a Swing JTree. Will let you know how it goes. Oks... Guess you are busy with your own coding hassles. Thanks for helping me out. Best -  Karl